# How to execute a SQL query in Azure Data Factory

Tags: sql-server, azure, cloud, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

I create a pipeline in ADF for performing copy activity. My source database is Azure SQL database and Sink is Azure Blob .I want to execute an SQL Query in ADF to delete data from source once data is copied to blob. I am not allowed to use copy or lookup to execute query.Is their any custom way to do this.I need to create a view and have to do some activity.Please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using data mapping flows, there is a new activity to execute custom SQL scripts:

- [Azure Data Factory mapping data flows adds SQL scripts to sink transformation](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/azure-data-factory-mapping-data-flows-adds-sql-scripts-to-sink-transformation/)

In a regular pipeline, you probably have to resort to using the Stored Procedure activity:

- [Transform data by using the SQL Server Stored Procedure activity in Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-using-stored-procedure)

You would have to write the delete logic in the SP, and then invoke the SP from Data Factory.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply unfortunately I am not able to use Data flow for  production. Still it is in preview mode.And i am facing some difficulty to create data stored procedure in azure data warehouse with parameter as table. table type creation is not allowed in data warehouse.

Answer (score 5):

You can also use the built-in stored procedure `sp_executesql`, which allows you to provide a random SQL statement as parameter.
That way you don't have to implement your own stored procedure.

See more information about this stored procedure on [sp_executesql (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Answer (score 0):

You can write a stored procedure for deleting the data from source table and call that stored procedure in "Stored procedure" activity after copy activity.

Your data flow will look like:

```
COPY ACTIVITY -----> STORED PROCEDURE ACTIVITY
```

Answer (score 0):

They have rolled out the **script activity**

The script task can be used for the following purposes:

Truncate a table or view in preparation for inserting data.
Create, alter, and drop database objects such as tables and views.
Re-create fact and dimension tables before loading data into them.
Run stored procedures. If the SQL statement invokes a stored procedure that returns results from a temporary table, use the WITH RESULT SETS option to define metadata for the result set.
Save the rowset returned from a query as activity output for downstream consumption.

**Script task is present under General tab of Activities.**

Ref 1
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-using-script

Ref 2
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-data-factory-blog/execute-sql-statements-using-the-new-script-activity-in-azure/ba-p/3239969

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31236984)

Comment: @AndrewHalil, Thanks for the suggestion. I have added the details.