# Can I connect a SQL Server Linked Server to Azure Data Factory?

Tags: sql-server, azure-data-factory, hana, linked-server

I have access to a Linked Server on SQL Server, lets call it LS1. It's connected to an SAP HANA database. I do not have direct access to the SAP HANA database; I only have access through the Linked Server on SQL Server.

[image: Linked Server]

In SSMS, I can access the table with the simple query:

```
Select * from LS1..<schema>.<table>
```

However, when I try that setup in Azure Data Factory (as shown below), I get the error `Invalid object name 'LS1..<schema>.<table>'` when I try to preview data.

[image: Failed query]

Interestingly, I get that same "error" as an IDE tooltip in SMSS, even though the query runs without problems. Has anyone been able to connect an Linked Server through ADF? Specifically an SAP HANA Linked Server with the stange `..` in the table path?

EDIT: I should have mentioned earlier that I have only select and insert rights on the SQL Server. I cannot create views or stored procedures.

Comment: `FYI` the `..` is really 2 object delimiters with a zero length string between, meaning that for the blank value the default will be used; in this case the `LOGIN`'s default database. It can also be used in other places, such as for the schema, where you may see `SELECT * FROM MyDatabase..MyTable;`. Here the `USER`'s default schema would be used; commonly `dbo`. It's use, however, is often frowned upon and the object should be specified.

Answer (score 2):

Create a [view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-view-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) or a [synonym](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-synonym-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to give the remote table a local object name.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have access to creating views on the server. I apologize for not originally including that in the question. I upvoted the question, but I don't feel right accepting it as an answer as I have no way of confirming that it would work.

Comment: Then try calling the sp_executesql stored procedure to run a custom query, as suggested in the second answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57820938/how-to-execute-a-sql-query-in-azure-data-factory