# Ezport data from azure synapse sql

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

We have azure synapse with external data source as azure dala lake gen2.

We need to export T-SQL query results as csv file on a weekly schedule from Azure synapse to any blob storage or FTP. I could not find  documents related to export from synapse. Please guide me through this - I've been stuck here for a long time.

Comment: are you using Azure Synapse dedicated pool? or serverless pool?

Comment: We are using serverless pool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57821076/3842610), I think the answer is:

1. Make a Dataflow where

   1. the source is the Synapse db and you pass the query you want
   2. the sink is a csv in ADLS gen2
2. Make an ADF pipeline with a weekly schedule trigger that calls your Dataflow

Comment: Thanks Anders, Whther this can be achieved through logic Apps if there is bulk data.